# How to use scrapy to crawl angularjs websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I need a way to get ALL odds of ALL events of bookmakers

I am using Scrapy+Splash to get the first javascript-loaded content of the site. But to get all other odds, I have to click "Spagna-LigaSpagnola", "Italia->Serie A", etc.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *emulate* behaviors, like a **scroll**, or a **click**, by writting a **JavaScript** script and by telling **Splash** to execute that script when it renders your page.

**A little exemple:**

You define a **JavaScript** function that selects an element in the page and then **clicks** on it:

(source: [splash doc](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-mouse-click))

```
  -- Get button element dimensions with javascript and perform mouse click.
_script = """
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    local get_dimensions = splash:jsfunc([[
        function () {
            var rect = document.getElementById('button').getClientRects()[0];
            return {"x": rect.left, "y": rect.top}
        }
    ]])
    splash:set_viewport_full()
    splash:wait(0.1)
    local dimensions = get_dimensions()
    splash:mouse_click(dimensions.x, dimensions.y)

    -- Wait split second to allow event to propagate.
    splash:wait(0.1)
    return splash:html()
end
"""
```

Then, when you `request`, you modify the `endpoint` and set it to `"execute"`, and you add `"lua_script": _script` to the **args**.

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield SplashRequest(response.url, self.parse_elem,
                        endpoint="execute",
                        args={"lua_source": _script})
```

You will find all the informations about **splash scripting** [**here**](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html#splash-scripts-tutorial)

Comment: It seems great. Is there a way to select and click a button in this way:
document.querySelectorAll(".list-group > a.list-group-item")[0].click(); ?